# Left alignment of the label format in a caption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I want to keep the label format of a caption at the left but center the caption text above/under the figure.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,
           top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]
           {geometry}
\usepackage{caption}   
\usepackage{float}
      
           
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
              singlelinecheck = false,
              labelsep=period,
              font={stretch=1.25}}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
text & text\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{here is some text.\\
here is some text again}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

What i want is:

[image]

Comment: What's should the maximal width of the caption text be? The full width of the textblock (aka `\textwidth`), or some fraction thereof? Please advise.

Comment: You have contradictory requirements.